# React: Selecting an element by id prints the wrong element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleRemoveItem(id) {
        const newResList = this.state.resolutions;

        function del(_i) { 
            delete newResList[_i];
        }

        let filtered = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < newResList.length; i++) {
            if(newResList[i].k === id) {
                let el = document.getElementById(newResList[i].title + newResList[i].k);
                //el.classList.remove('animate__fadeInDown');
                //el.classList.add('animate__fadeOutLeft');
                console.log(el);
                del(i); // delete newResList[i]
            }
        }
        filtered = newResList.filter(function(el) {
            return el != null;
        });
        console.log(filtered);
        this.setState({resolutions: filtered});
    }
```

Hello! So, I am working on this list in react, when I add two elements to my list, and remove the first one added, it prints the other element that is left in the list. Is this normal? the 'id' is applied on creation of the list element and contains the title + unique ID applied to the object.

Not to say that removing the list element doesn't work, but I've commented out the adding/removing of classes in this code because its being applied to the wrong element!

Any help is greatly appreciated

---

Comment: Hi, when you work with react you don't have to interact with the DOM directly. This is done by react.

Comment: Firstly, do not use delete operator on arrays elements. That's not how it works in JS - just read some basic JS reference on Arrays built-in methods. Secondly, never mutate react-component's state  - you should set a new state instead.

Comment: When working in react you almost never use dom query methods. You modify the data in the state that react uses to render the dom. You are going to need to seriously change how you think about the react app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when working with React there is a virtual DOM which handles all `id`'s and function calls by the react logic.

If you want to, for example, select a element, there is no need to do it. Call a function directly from the element itself with `onClick` attribute and when other elements depend on this change, introduce state which you manipulate then.

More in the React Doc:
https://reactjs.org/

Comment: Well the button to remove the list element is a <button> within the <li> and i need to apply the animation the <li> is there a way I can get the parent of the element I clicked?

Comment: I recommend reading about flux architecture which is used in React. Shortly speaking, you would normally pass the handler-function from parent to child element. Than you trigger it on/withing the childs element's click-handler function